# Evaluate $|\{(C_1,C_2)\in \mathcal P(M)\times\mathcal P(M)|A\subseteq C_1\subseteq C_2\subseteq B\}|$ for $|B\setminus A|=n$

Tags: real-analysis, binomial-coefficients

Let $M$ be a finite set and $f(A,B):=|\{C\in \mathcal P(M)|A\subseteq C\subseteq B\}|$.

For $n=|B\setminus A|$ we have $$f(A,B)=\sum_{C \in \mathcal P(M)\\A\subseteq C\subseteq B}1=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{C \in \mathcal P(M)\\|C\setminus A|=k}1=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}=2^n$$

Let $g(A,B):=|\{(C_1,C_2)\in \mathcal P(M)\times\mathcal P(M)|A\subseteq C_1\subseteq C_2\subseteq B\}|$

How can I determine $g(A,B)$?
$$g(A,B)=\sum_{(C_1,C_2)\in \mathcal P(M)\times\mathcal P(M)\\A\subseteq C_1\subseteq C_2\subseteq B}1=?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any order pair $(C_1,C_2)$ such that $A\subseteq C_1 \subseteq C_2 \subseteq B$ can be uniquely derived from the following counting procedure.

Assign each element of $B-A$ to one of the following three options. $$\text{Option #1: Go to }C_1   \text{ and } C_2  \\ \text{Option #2: Don't go to }C_1   \text{ and go to } C_2 \\ \text{Option #3: Don't go to }C_1   \text{ nor } C_2$$ Each of the $3^{|B-A|}$ ways to prescribe these options will provide you with a distinct ordered pair $(C_1,C_2)$ with $A\subseteq C_1 \subseteq C_2 \subseteq B$. For example, suppose $A=\{1,2\},B=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Then the ordered pair $(C_1,C_2)=\left(\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,3,5\}\right)$ uniquely corresponds to the assignment of options to elements of $B-A$: $$3:\text{Option #1} \\ 4:\text{Option #3} \\ 5: \text{Option #2} $$ So, if $A\subseteq B$ such that $|B-A|=n$, then $g(A,B)=3^n$